Problem in extracting human silhouettes from a segmented image (felzenszwalb)
I am currently working on extracting binary silhouette of people in an image in the publicly available UT interaction dataset. I have applied felzenszwalb's segmentation on the image to divide the image into segments according to the intensity and spatial locations. Then I have to somehow extract binary silhouette of the people in the image. The problem is that I am unable to extract the binary silhouettes for the people in the images properly. Here is the original image:

Here is the segmented image after applying felzenszwalb's segmentation with a parameter value of scale = 200 and sigma = 0.8 where each color in the image represents a segment.

Here is the binary image after applying some threshold to extract binary silhouette where I put some values to exclude segments that have intensity less than a threshold and have height, width and area higher than a threshold:

Finally, here is the binary image after applying morphological erosion with iteration 1:

Now as you can see, those segments have become part of the binary silhouettes as well that do not belong to any of the two people. Even after morphological erosion operations, these segments do not get removed properly. I tried morphological erosion operations with different iterations and different parameter values for the segmentation algorithm, where it can other either prioritize creating large segments ignoring small changes among pixels or creating small segments where it prioritizes even the smallest changes depending on the parameter value. The segmentation and binary silhouette extraction works well for some images, but I have to change the parameters in the segmentation algorithm, threshold values in binary silhouette extraction and iterations for morphological erosion for many images. I want to automate this process, but I just cannot find some method that works for all images in the dataset properly. What can I do?
Here is the code:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage.segmentation as seg
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.measure import regionprops


def morphological_erosion(binary_silhouette):

    # Create a structuring element (consider different shapes)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)  # Basic 3x3 square
    
    binary_silhouette = cv2.erode(binary_silhouette, kernel, iterations= 1)

    return binary_silhouette

def felzenszwalb_segmentation(rgb_image):
 
    # Perform segmentation using Felzenszwalb's method
    segments = seg.felzenszwalb(rgb_image, scale=200, sigma=0.8, min_size = 50)

    # Generate random colors for each segment
    num_segments = len(np.unique(segments))
    colors = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(num_segments, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Create a blank RGB image of the same size as the input image
    segmented_image = np.zeros_like(rgb_image)
    
    # Assign random colors to each segment
    for segment_id in np.unique(segments):
        mask = (segments == segment_id)
        segmented_image[mask] = colors[segment_id]

    # display the segmented image
    cv2.imshow("segmented Image", segmented_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return segments

def create_binary_silhoutte(image_segments, image):
    
    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray_image = rgb2gray(image)

    # Create an empty binary image
    binary_image = np.zeros_like(gray_image)
   
    # Calculate the mean intensity of each segment
    for region in regionprops(image_segments, intensity_image=gray_image):
        # Get the mean intensity of the segment
        mean_intensity = region.mean_intensity
        area = region.area
         # Get bounding box coordinates
        min_row, min_col, max_row, max_col = region.bbox
        
        # Calculate height and width
        height = max_row - min_row
        width = max_col - min_col

        # If the mean intensity is greater than the threshold, mark the region in the binary image
        if mean_intensity > 0.5 and area < 50000 and height < 500 and width < 500:  
            for coordinates in region.coords:
                binary_image[coordinates[0], coordinates[1]] = 255
    

    return binary_image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # # Example usage
    image_path =  # path to image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Apply Felzenszwalb segmentation to get the silhouette
    segments = felzenszwalb_segmentation(image)
    
    binary_silhouette = create_binary_silhoutte(segments, image)

    cv2.imshow("binary Silhouette", binary_silhouette)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    binary_silhouette = morphological_erosion(binary_silhouette)

    cv2.imshow("binary Silhouette", binary_silhouette)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I also tried using some noise removal algorithms like bilateral filter before applying the segmentation, but it did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Your question appears to be more about strategies for image analysis than programming, since there's not really a programming issue here? You also seem to be specifically after shapes that are 'human-like', but your approach finds large triangular shapes that are obviously not human to us as well, and you likely need a strategy to identify what parts of the image are humans. From the images in this case, it would appear that further eroding and shrinking the shapes to make them come apart, somehow identifying human-like ones, and then returning to the segmentation could be a viable strategy.

those segments don't carry semantics (none that I can see). that approach to segmentation looks unsuitable to obtain human silhouettes. this needs machine learning.

@ChristophRackwitz , I actually found a research paper that used the strategy I was using where they first applied segmentation and then the binary silhouette extraction but on a different dataset. I emailed the authors about this but no response. Here is the research paper link: link. Do you think that the researchers might have manually extracted the silhouettes first by changing parameters for each image? Because I don't think that it is possible to automate this even using the dataset used by the authors.

their approach involving Felzenszwalb (Felsen Schwalbe) accidentally worked because their videos contain uniform grayish-beige backgrounds. if they were gonna use deep learning anyway, they should have just used state of the art semantic segmentation or instance segmentation for their human silhouettes.

@beaker I converted the image into gray scale to extract only those segments for binary silhouette that have intensity higher than a threshold and pass the height, width criteria. Can you suggest any other method of silhouette extraction?

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks. Surely, the strategy they used depends a lot on the dataset.

Agree with @ChristophRackwitz.  I don't think Felzenszwalb is going to be particularly pixel-by-pixel accurate for this sort of activity.  Note that Felzenszwalb predates a lot of the recent state-of-the-art ML developments, so I think that at the time it was pretty awesome, but what with the breakneck pace of image processing research, there are now much better options for this task.

I'd used Felzenszwalb's segmentation with a parameter value of scale=650, sigma=3, min_size=1000, this will give the following result:

Then you can iterate over segmented labels and use morphological opening and clear border to extract the silhouettes.
Here is the full code:
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import segmentation, morphology

image_path = # path to image
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Apply Felzenszwalb segmentation to get the silhouette
segments_fz = segmentation.felzenszwalb(image, scale=650, sigma=3, min_size=1000)

# Create an empty binary image
binary_silhouettes = np.zeros_like(segments_fz)

for l in np.unique(segments_fz):
    # Disconnect objects
    silhouette = morphology.opening(segments_fz==l, morphology.diamond(3))

    # Clear objects connected to the image border
    silhouette = segmentation.clear_border(silhouette)
    
    # Remove small objects, i.e. objects with area<1000 will be removed
    silhouette = morphology.area_opening(silhouette, 1000)

    # Aggregate silhouette masks
    binary_silhouettes += silhouette

plt.imshow(binary_silhouettes)


The final result would be this:

or if we apply the mask to original image, like this:
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask_3d = np.repeat(binary_silhouettes[:,:,np.newaxis], 3, axis=-1)
plt.imshow(mask_3d * image_rgb)

we will have:

For more general approach you can try to use SAM model, something like this (please run this on GPU):
from transformers.utils import logging
from transformers import pipeline
import requests
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
logging.set_verbosity_error()

device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

sam_pipe = pipeline("mask-generation",
    "Zigeng/SlimSAM-uniform-77", device=device)

image_url = "https://i.sstatic.net/nSG3oqmP.png"
img_data = requests.get(image_url).content
with open('image.png', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
img = Image.open("image.png")

output = sam_pipe(img, points_per_batch=32)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 20))
axes[0].imshow(~output['masks'][output['scores'].argmax()])
axes[1].imshow(output['masks'][11])
axes[2].imshow(output['masks'][16])
axes[0].axis("off")
axes[1].axis("off")
axes[2].axis("off")
plt.show()


For faster executions you can identify points where potential silhouettes can appear, and give them to be segmented.

Any thoughts on how well this code will generalize to other images?

Images similar to this would probably work. But the approach is biased by the background and sizes of persons. With more complex background or smaller (<1000) silhouettes, or with complex clothing texture this will not work. But you cat try to adapt better thresholds. For good generalization you may try segment anything model: https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything
